# Display a view containing magnified image along with some text

Tags: android

I have a listview having a two textviews and an image. When I touch the image, I want to display a view containing a magnified iamge along with some text below it an option to close that view. I don't want to create a whole new activity for this.
Kindly assist how can achieve this?

Stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use custom dialog box.
[Custom Dialog](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)

Comment: http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-display-custom-dialog-and.html

Comment: I am curious to know if this really offers the best user experience? Sometimes its easy to see that the dialog takes a moment (and in most cases not any longer) to launch. I think there is a smoother way of achieving this.